# User Controls and XML Namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, namespaces

When using xml namespaces (xmlns:) in WPF, is there a different way you need to specify a namespace? I was trying to implement a User Control, but it kept giving me the following error: "The name '' does not exist in the namespace 'clr-namespace:myNamespace' ."

Any tips concerning xml namespaces (especially when trying to access classes) would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I keep getting the following error when attempting to add a custom user control to my main window: "The name 'customControl' does not exist in the namespace 'clr-namespace:MovableDataGridRows_test.userControls'. "

Below is the XAML code to my main window:

```
<Window x:Class="MovableDataGridRows_test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls_c="clr-namespace:MovableDataGridRows_test.userControls"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">


    <Controls_c:customControl width="300"/>
</Window>
```

Below is the XAML code for my user control that I wish to include in my main window(NOTE: The user control is in a folder in the project named, "userControl". The project name is, "MovableDataGridRows_test"):

```
<UserControl x:Class="MovableDataGridRows_test.userControls.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Margin="223,0,0,263">Submit</Button>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Check the assembly as well. Could you show the code so we can have a better chance of diagnosing your issue?

Comment: `xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly"`

Omitting the `;assembly=MyAssembly"` part is only allowed if the namespace you are mapping is in the same assembly as in the user control.

Check out this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).